# improve performance of finding rolling window maximum likelihood

Tags: maximum-likelihood, references, online-algorithms, moving-window

There is data indexed by time:

$$
D_1, D_2, D_3, ..., D_T
$$

I have a model that I assume the parameter $\theta_t$ changes with time $t$. 
As a result, I adapt a rolling window strategy:

$$
\theta_{t+1} = \underset{\theta}{\arg \max}~~\mbox{L}(\theta~; D_1, D_2, D_3, ..., D_{t})
$$

i.e.

$$
\theta_{t+n} = \underset{\theta}{\arg \max}~~\mbox{L}(\theta~; D_n, D_{n+1}, ..., D_{t+n})
$$

My problem is: fitting each model for each time step is very time-consuming. My optimization routine takes around 2 minutes and I have thousands of such data.

Are there any technique in statistics that I can exploit the structure of rolling window (i.e. using the previous estimation $\theta_{t}$ and the little difference between two likelihood function) to get $\theta_{t+1}$ quickly?

One thing is that I must use MLE. Not MAP nor something else.

**Remarks**: I am already using the previous point $\theta_{t}$ for the initial guess point for $\theta_{t+1}$.

Comment: How many iterations  your optimization routine needs to find $\theta_{t+1}$?

Comment: around ~130 iterations, ~ 900 evaluations of the function, ~200 evaluations of the gradient. 

If I use a warm initial point (as in said in the remarks), I can reduce it by around 10%. I computed $\frac{||\theta_{t+1} - \theta_{t}||}{\theta_{t}}$ ~= 0.08. As it is a log-likelihood function, the objective function between two optimizations are different by two (log-) density function.